# Evaluating einstein summation using numexpr

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-einsum, numexpr

I am currently working with large numpy array multiplications, using `numpy.einsum`, and have been facing `MemoryError` issue. That is why I'm trying to evaluate expressions, wherever possible, with `numexpr`. As far as I understand:

```
np.einsum('ij,j -> ij', a, b)
```

is technically the same as

```
numexpr.evaluate("a*b")
```

However, things seems to be not so straightforward in other cases. Suppose I have three expressions:

```
np.einsum('i, j -> ij', a, b)
np.einsum('ij, i -> ij', a, b)
np.einsum(ijk, kl -> ijkl', a, b)
```

What would be the equivalent way of achieving these three using `numexpr`?

Comment: There exists no convenient 1:1 mapping between one and the other. However, if you know what one does, you can just spell it out with the other.

Comment: All those examples can be expressed as `*` multiplication with broadcasting.  They don't involve any `dot` like summation of products, just some form of `outer` product.  e.g. `a[:,None]*b`, `a*b[:,None]`, `a[...,None]*b`.

Comment: @hpalj what is the advantage of expressing as `*` in comparision to just the ususal `einsum`?

Comment: Usually einsum is used for selected sums of products, not just products.